# Simple floating point benchmark that can be compiled from source?

Tags: linux, arm, benchmark, floating-point

I am interested in benchmarking some ARM platforms; can anyone suggest a simple benchmark with source code that can be used to benchmark floating point performance?  A package such as a .deb file would not work, as some of these platforms do not support packages.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You'll find a number of floating-point benchmarks on http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/; I tried a couple just now, and while some are so old they give meaningless results now (Whetstone for example), http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/linpackc.new seems to produce usable results. It needs nothing special to build:

```
wget http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/linpackc.new
mv linpackc.new linpack.c
gcc -O3 -march=native linpack.c -o linpack -lm
./linpack
```

(This is a simple version of the [LINPACK benchmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINPACK_benchmarks) which is the standard used for comparing super-computer floating-point performance; the implementation used for the TOP-500 comparison is available at http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/hpl/ but it requires a couple of support libraries.)

If you want to benchmark other components of the system, check out [LMbench](http://www.bitmover.com/lmbench/get_lmbench.html); it comes as source code and also compiles without any special libraries. You might need to tweak things a little so the build works:

```
tar xf lmbench3.tar.gz
cd lmbench3
mkdir SCCS
touch SCCS/s.ChangeSet bk.ver
cd src
make results
```

then follow the prompts.

Comment: Also, don't forget to enable optimisations when compiling `gcc -O3 -march=native` at the minimum.